# MongoDB - Usar .distinct em 2 propriedades de um documento

Tags: mongodb

Eu tenho o seguinte conjunto de dados no meu banco:

```
{ "_id": 1, "dept": "A", "item": { "format": "circle", "color": "red" }}
{ "_id": 2, "dept": "A", "item": { "format": "circle", "color": "blue" }}
{ "_id": 3, "dept": "B", "item": { "format": "rect", "color": "green" }}
{ "_id": 4, "dept": "A", "item": { "format": "rect", "color": "geen" }}
{ "_id": 5, "dept": "B", "item": { "format": "circle", "color": "blue" }}
{ "_id": 6, "dept": "A", "item": { "format": "rect", "color": "blue" }}
{ "_id": 7, "dept": "B", "item": { "format": "circle", "color": "blue" }}
```

Eu preciso distingui-los baseado em `format` e em `color`.
O resultado deve ser assim:

```
{"format" : "circle", color : "red"}
{"format" : "circle", color : "blue"}
{"format" : "rect", color : "green"}
{"format" : "rect", color : "blue"}
```

Eu tentei usar a função [distinc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/).

```
db.collection.distinct('item.format')
```

Porém a mesma só suporta uma propriedade

Usando a função [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) eu não consigo distinguir as propriedades.

Algo como:

```
db.getCollection().aggregate([
    { $group : { 
        _id : {
            format: '$item.format',
            color : '$item.color'
        }
    }},
])
```

Não distingue os itens por `format` ou `color` nem os agrupa em um mesmo JSON.
Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o método [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) resolveria a sua situação.

Ele primeiro separaria os itens do item e depois você daria o [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

```
db.getCollection().aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$item'},
    { $group : { 
        _id : {
            format: '$item.format',
            color : '$item.color'
        }
    }},
])
```

Comment: Isso funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!